# Story Progression through if blocks and variables: Failure

Tags: python, if-statement, save

Ok. I'm designing a small text-based RPG, however, I need to have the player be able to save the game. I've succeeded in doing this through using the pickle module, but I'm trying to get the player to be able to get back to their previous point in the storyline through using this variable I call 'storypointe'. Basically it would work like this:

```
if storypointe == 0:
    #Story, story, stuff happens here...
    storypointe += 1

if storypointe == 1:
    #More story, more story, more stuff happens here....
```

I would then pickle the variable storypointe, and when the game is loaded (meaning using pickle.load to get player stats and storypointe from whatever file I pickled it into), and IDEALLY it would just start from whichever code block storypointe corresponds to. The actual code is way too much work for the writer and (perhaps) the readers, so I've written the following code that simulates the same environment and replicates the same problem.

```
storypointe = 0
jump = 0
spin = 0
dive = 0
roar = 0
savefile = "C:\Users\Sammu\The Folder\databin.txt"
import pickle, sys



def save ():
    with open(savefile, 'w') as savebin:
        actions = [jump, spin, dive, roar, storypointe]
        pickle.dump (actions, savebin)

def load ():
    with open(savefile, 'r') as loadbin:
        actions2 = pickle.load (loadbin)
        print actions2

        jump = actions2[0]
        spin = actions2[1]
        dive = actions2[2]
        roar = actions2[3]
        storypointe = actions2[4]


#Begin the code#

gameIO = raw_input ('Would you like to load previous game?\n>>> ')

if gameIO in ['yes', 'load', 'load game', 'Yes', 'Load', 'Load game']:
    load () 

if storypointe == 0:
    action = raw_input ('Would you like to jump, spin, dive or roar?\n>>> ')

    if action in ['jump', 'Jump']:
        jump += 1
        print jump

    if action in ['spin', 'Spin']:
        spin += 1
        print spin

    if action in ['dive', 'Dive']:
        dive += 1
        print dive

    if action in ['roar', 'Roar']:
        roar += 1
        print roar


    storypointe += 1

if storypointe == 1:
    print "\n\nYou have progressed to the next stage"
    save ()
```

So if storypointe is equal to actions2[4], then that must mean it should be equal to 1. But the problem here is that it's always following the first code block, starting from

```
action = raw_input ('#yadayadayada')
```

instead of:

```
print "You have progressed to the next stage"
```

Comment: You say it *should* be equal to 1, but is it *actually* equal to 1?  Include print statements to see what the value actually is.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use a giant switch statement like that. Make an array of functions and put them in a dict.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confused about Python scoping.

Here you make a new variable at module level:

```
storypointe = 0

[...]
```

But here:

```
def load ():
    with open(savefile, 'r') as loadbin:
        actions2 = pickle.load (loadbin)

[...]
        storypointe = actions2[4]
```

you simply make a new *local* name "storypointe" in the function `load`.  It doesn't affect what `storypointe` is at the module level.  I would store your variables in a class or a dict instead, which would also prevent having to do the `actions2[i]` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than express your narrative as a bunch of if statements consider it as a state machine, if you express your story-line as a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) then you can easily store routes through the game as references to the next `node` in the tree, you can also store references (unique) to each node, allowing for easy saving and loading of positions.

See for example

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, children=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = children or {}

story = {}
story['a'] = Node(None)
story['b'] = Node(a)
story['a'].children['b'] = story['b']
```